# Implement insertion-ordered dictionary in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I want to create a dictionary, similar to NSMutableDictionary, but have it keep the insertion order of the elements. What is the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try keeping an NSArray for the dictionary's keys. Each time you insert entry to you dictionary, you will also insert the key to the array. The array will preserve the insertion order, and if you'll want to get the value of the first inserted entry, you can just pull it by asking the value for the first key in the array.

Comment: Wow! Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

As you know for NSDictionary there is no rules to keep their insertion order. If I make this, I would keep an order with a value in NSArray as a wrapper value.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mutableDic = @{@"key" : @[val, order]}
```